# How to create a mailbox on a custom Cyrus IMAP partition with IMAP API for PHP?

Tags: php, imap

Let's say you have multiple volumes on your storage drive for storing IMAP mailboxes, and it's about a Linux-based mail server:

```
/var/imap/imap-default
/var/imap/imap-1
/var/imap/imap-2
/var/imap/imap-3
```

How to use PHP and its IMAP API to create a new mailbox on the specified partition, not the default one? If that's not feasible with the standard PHP IMAP API, is there an API which doesn't wrap the Linux shell tools?

Comment: phps imap extension opens remote mailboxes for usage, it does not create local ones. You certainly can use it on the same system as your mails should be stored on, but still the extension acts as a client to an imap server. So if you want to create imap mailboxes, then you have to do that using an imap server.

Comment: @Arkascha: I am using the standard PHP IMAP extension, but it doesn't seem to offer the option of creating mailboxes on partitions other than default.

Comment: Did you even bother to read and understand my comment? Sorry, but it does not appear so... Or it is me who got something completely wrong here. Could you please post the code you use in the question above? (there is an `edit` button)

Comment: @Arkascha: I've read your comment, and if I understand it correctly, you're claiming it isn't possible to create a mailbox using PHP IMAP API at all, but it is. I just can't find a way to store the mailbox on the wanted partition. The `imap_createmailbox` function doesn't have a partition parameter.

Comment: Please note that `imap_createmailbox()` creates a new mail box _on the imap server_ you connected to using an `imap_open()` call. It cannot somehow interact with the local file system. That is not how it works. Once again: phps imap extension implements an imap _client_. A client interacts with a matching server, not with the file system.

Comment: @Arkascha: Where does it say that I want to create a mailbox on the local file system? :-) I want to create it on the server, but not on the default partition.

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes more sense. But it is not possible AFAIK. Are you sure the imap protocol oven offers such feature? I mean doing so would be against all good practices in security. A client dictating a server how to use the server side resources? Not a good idea... You see in general the imap protocol access a file hierarchy, so a tree of virtual folders. A file hierarchy does not have a concept of "volumes" or similar. It is up to the server to map the virtual file hierarchy it exposes to the client onto physical volumes on the server side hardware.

Comment: @Arkascha: Yes, you can specify the partition you want by using the `cyradm` shell tool which interacts with Cyrus IMAP mail server. I could create a wrapper around this shell tool, but that's not a nice solution. The end goal is to create a GUI tool for the mail server administrator (the one who creates mail accounts and mailboxes), not the client who just reads e-mail inside Thunderbird or Outlook.

Comment: That might very well be, but that does not make that feature part of the imap protocol. phps imap extension implements an imap client, not a client for possible protocol extensions of some specific imap server implementation. That feature is to control the servers behavior (it is a server administration utility!), such feature should not be present within a normal client. That would raise huge security issues. Sorry, but what you try simply is not possible with a normal imap client.

Comment: What you are looking for is a cyrus administration extension for php. I doubt such exists.